# RedirectMatch error with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following directive in my .htaccess file which works on one server, but not another:

```
RedirectMatch hobby/RENDER/0001/2015/P2015.html$ http://www.escience.ca/hobby/RENDER/0001/2015/3035/W3035.html [L]
```

On one of the servers, it gives me a 500 Internal Server Error.  If I comment out the RedirectMatch, the 500 error goes away.  This is the error message I see in the apache2 error.log

```
/var/www/escience.ca/public_html/.htaccess: Redirect: invalid first argument (of three)
```

Apache's rewrite and alias modules are running.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The [L] flag does appear to work with RedirectMatch in my version of Apache2.